# How to get binding object in change event in Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My code sample:

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account" indexVar="index">
    <ui:inputText value="{!account.FirstName}" change="{!c.saveAccount}" />
 </aura:iteration>

 saveAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
    // is it possible to get account here?
 }
```

I want to get the item from array for which event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change ui:inputText to lightning:input, but solution looks a bit like a hack

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account" indexVar="index">  
    <lightning:input value="{!account.FirstName}" onblur="{!c.saveAccount}" name="{!'acc' + index}" label=" " variant="label-hidden"/>
 </aura:iteration>

 saveAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
    let index = parseInt(event.getSource().get("v.name").split("acc")[1]);
    let account = component.get("v.accounts")[index];
 }
```